# South error, but not using it. "no South database module 'south.db.mysql'"

Tags: django, django-south

After installing of Django I get this error message (when I want to run migrations or runserver):

> There is no South database module 'south.db.mysql' for your database.
>   Please either choose a supported database, check for
>   SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from
>   INSTALLED_APPS.

I dont want to use South and it is also not defined in INSTALLED_APPS . Why am I getting this error?

Comment: you need to post more information, maybe a full stacktrace for the above error

Comment: @Anentropic , this is the full message.

Comment: do you have `SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER` defined in settings?

Comment: I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out South got installed after all because of some dependency,
and seems to be incompatible with current Django (1.82)

Solution that worked for me was to downgrade Django:

```
$ pip install -U "Django==1.7"
```

(ps. I didn't need to define anything about South in settings, so it is not used, but probably some installed app is looking for it anyway..)

Comment: I've had this issue before, with the Wagtail CMS. It was easy enough to remove. This underlines the wisdom of the DSF in deciding to bring migrations into Django, since almost every project had it as a requirement!

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error. It is resolved by removing `south` from your environment , by running
`pip uninstall south`

Comment: Seems to be some old package that tries to import south, and if it works tries to run migrations using south. Uninstalling south makes it use modern migrations.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated this issue by doing these steps:

1. Installed django1.5 and south.
2. With the environment, Created a django project.
3. Upgrade django1.5 to django1.82

Now in runserver, 
I've `There is no South database module 'south.db.mysql' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS.`

Possible solution:

1. Uninstall south if you are in django1.82
2. Downgrade your django, where south is a different package.